# Are "1" and 1 the same thing?

Tags: string, integer, ascii

Not language specific, but is "1" and 1 the same thing?
When looking at the ascii tables the integer 1 is denoted by 049, but what about "1"?

Answer (score 1):

It is a character, not an integer.

> ASCII, abbreviated from American Standard Code for Information Interchange, is a character encoding standard for electronic communication. ASCII codes represent text in computers, telecommunications equipment, and other devices

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Ironically, the 049 *is* the integer, representing the character "1".
In this manner, 001 is the second character in the ASCII Table which is `SOH` (Start of Heading).